# add icon to the navigation bar

Tags: android, android-navigation

i have an activity, i want to add a navigation bar to it.

i want to support api less that 8 . i did all of that.

#### my problem

all the navigation bar in my application contains the `application name` and the `application icon`.

#### my question

how can i customize those information ? i mean the test and the icon.

#### things that might help

i specify the parent of any activity in the manifest like this

```
<meta-data 
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainCustomerMenu2"
                />
```

i add this theme to my activity that has the navigation bar

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

#### more

i have read this official document http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html but it didnt answer my question

Comment: I found the solution, which is a predefined function called `setIcon`. i was an idiot sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

`getActionBar().setLogo()` or `getSupportActionBar().setLogo()` if you're using the support v4 pacakge